# Travis CI JDK set to oraclejdk8, but getting errors that say source is 1.5

Tags: java, travis-ci

I'm having some difficulty getting Travis CI running.  I though my .yml file was set correctly to use java 8, but I'm getting errors that say otherwise.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T17:29:23+00:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_31, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-042stab105.14", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building HonestMistakesWPINav 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ HonestMistakesWPINav ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 7 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ HonestMistakesWPINav ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 24 source files to /home/travis/build/theflanman/HonestMistakesWPINav/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/travis/build/theflanman/HonestMistakesWPINav/src/main/gui/DevGUIFront.java:[214,92] lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.506 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-24T18:19:53+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/134M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project HonestMistakesWPINav: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/travis/build/theflanman/HonestMistakesWPINav/src/main/gui/DevGUIFront.java:[214,92] lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

As far as I can tell, maven is recognizing that I'm using java 8, but travis is compiling in 1.5.  I can't find anything anywhere about how to change that, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to set the Java version in the configuration for the compiler plugin in your POM.

Answer (score 1):

What does your travis.yml look like?

These are the first three lines of mine and this works fine for me (I'm using gradle instead of maven)

```yaml
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
```

You're going to have to provide more information for anyone to help with this one.

For reference this is my full [travis.yml](https://github.com/WPIRoboticsProjects/GRIP/blob/master/.travis.yml) for reference.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved a similar problem adding these two lines on my .travis.yml file:

```
install: mvn install -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.8 -Dmaven.compiler.source=1.8 -DskipTests=true
script: mvn test -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.8 -Dmaven.compiler.source=1.8
```

Or you can indicate which JDK version is used during compilation via your POM.xml:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Both approaches work for me.